# Meaning of fundamental interval in Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, definition, fourier-series

> Question: The Fourier series expansion for the periodic function,
> $$
>  f(t) = |\sin(t)|
>  $$
> is defined in its fundamental interval. Taking $\pi = 3.142$, calculate the Fourier cosine series approximation of $f(t)$, up to the 6th harmonics when $t = 2.12$. Give your answer to 3 decimal places.

I have trouble understanding the meaning of fundamental interval.
Does it mean that $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the fundamental interval is the smallest period of the given function, so in this case $[0,\pi]$.